# NSString compare returning NSOrderedDescending instead of NSOrderedSame

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsstream

I am receiving the data in an iPad application from a socket connected.
I am converting the data received to NSString using the method below:

```
NSString *data = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding].
```

Then I am creating a substring from the string using the

```
NSString *substring1 = [data substringFromIndex:length-9]
NSString *substring2 = [data substringFromIndex:length-3]
```

where length is [data length].

Then I am comparing the `substring2` with  `@"/>"` string as below 
    `[substring2 compare:@"/>"]`
Here I checked the value of the `substring2` while debugging the application the value is `@"/>"`
but the comparison result is returned as `NSOrderedDescending` instead of `NSOrderedSame`.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: can you print what string you have in string data?

Comment: try `[substring2 isEqualToString:@"/>"]`

Answer (score 0):

Your string is having trailing space. The string which you are extracting as length - 3, it must be of length 3.

Now you are comparing it with `@"/>"` which is having length 2.

You need to do it be below way:

```
NSString *data = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding].
data = [data stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

Now take the substring and compare.